# Apply for Germany work visa from other than my home country

Tags: working-visas

I am currently working in Hong Kong on a work visa. Now, I would like to move to Germany for work. Can I apply for a work visa from Hong Kong? I have an Indian passport. I found that Germany has its consulate office Hong Kong but I'm not sure whether they allow to apply from Hong Kong or not. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you are working in HK on a work visa, you have an ID card, and thus are a resident. This is your place of residence, and you can apply from the German consulate in HK. Consulates in HK usually require a copy of the HK (or Macao) ID card when processing a visa application.